# ROS camera snapshot save as jpg

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm working to detect circles using cv.houghcirles, which I have working... but as soon as the camera moves cv.houghcircles crashes.  So my next plan was to take snap shots and save the images run cv.houghcircles on the images to get point location back.

So long story short, I need a way to save a ROS gazebo camera as a jpg, bmp, etc.

any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43395/ros-camera-snapshot-save-as-jpg/) by [ncr7](https://answers.ros.org/users/2800/ncr7/) on ROS Answers with karma: 325 on 2012-09-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ah... I was hoping to find something to create it automatically through code.  I think there might be a way in by using cv.EncodeImage, but I haven't been able to get the code working the way I want yet. Found an example used [here](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/changeset/2230/trunk/opencv/tests/python/test.py)

As for my OpenCV circle problem, I was able to get cv.HoughCircles to work without crashing... basically by just drawing a circle in a corner of the ROS camera and making sure the camera feed was not moving to fast for opencv by using rospy.sleep(1.0), I posted the code here... might be useful for anyone using a camera feed in ROS and opencv.

```
    cv_image = self.convert_image(data)
    rospy.sleep(1.0)
    cv.Circle(cv_image, (100,100), 100, 255, 3, 8, 0)
    gray = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(cv_image), 8, 1)
    #edges = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(cv_image), 8, 1)
    cvSize = cv.GetSize(cv_image)
    cv.CvtColor(cv_image, gray, cv.CV_BGR2GRAY)
    cv.Canny(gray, gray, 50, 200, 3)
    cv.Smooth(gray, gray, cv.CV_GAUSSIAN, 7, 7)
    
    storage = cv.CreateMat(cv_image.rows, 1, cv.CV_32FC3)

    cv.HoughCircles(gray, storage, cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 2, cvSize[0]/4, 100, 250)
```

---

Originally posted by [ncr7](https://answers.ros.org/users/2800/ncr7/) with karma: 325 on 2012-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [image_view](http://www.ros.org/wiki/image_view#image_view.2BAC8-diamondback.Viewing_a_single_image_topic) package will save a JPG file each time you click on the viewing window.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-09-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1